# Meaning of Inappropriately appropriative

Tags: vocabulary

Could someone please elaborate on its usage with examples. Where can I use it ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember to be specific in your question, to provide a context for any examples or quotes, and to demonstrate what research you have attempted thus far. Without other context, *inappropriately appropriative* would simply have a literal meaning based on the dictionary definitions of *inappropriately* and *appropriative*: something or someone is appropriative in an inappropriate manner or fashion. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: It's a playful juxtaposition of two similar-looking but essentially unrelated words.  If you look them up separately in a dictionary you will easily grasp the overall meaning (and, since only you know the context, you'll understand the meaning in this case better than we can).

Answer (score 0):

I read "appropriative" here as "adopting the style or manner of". To say that something is inappropriately appropriative is to say that someone is taking on the style of another in an improper way. An example might be, it is inappropriately appropriative for privileged kids at a New England boarding school to use strong southern accents with fractured grammar. Back in the day, some people complained about Paul Simon's musical collaboration with Ladysmith Black Mambozo (IIRC) - the idea was that he was appropriating a musical style and tradition for commercial gain without having lived the experiences that gave rise to that tradition. He was inappropriately appropriating African musical styles. The real meaning of the phrase, though, is quite possibly a simple flexing of syllabic muscles. Showing off.